# How to print two lines from two text files opposite to each other instead of one by one printing in C?

Tags: c, file, printing, io

```
...char* status1, * status2;
    char ch1[255],ch2[255];
    FILE* fptr1;
    FILE* fptr2;
    char buf1[0x100];
    char buf2[0x100];
    snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1), "%s.txt", text);
    snprintf(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "%s.txt", text);
    fptr1 = fopen(buf1, "r");
    fptr2 = fopen(buf2, "r");

//  fptr = fopen(folder[5]+*c[i].val+text[3], "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL && fptr2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open files \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Read contents from file 

    do {
        status1 = fgets(ch1, sizeof(ch1), fptr1);
        status2 = fgets(ch2, sizeof(ch2), fptr1);
        printf("File 1: %s", ch1);
        printf("File 2: %s", ch2);
    }while (status1||status2);
    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);...
```

I am trying to print lines from two different files opposite to each other like this one

```
------------  ------------
-3--------3-  -3--------3-
------------  ------------
------------  ------------
------------  ------------
------------  ------------
------------  ------------
-3--------3-  -3--------3-
------------  ------------
```

but getting in

```
------------
 -3--------3-
 ------------
 ------------
 ------------
 ------------
 ------------
 -3--------3-
 ------------
 -3--------3-
 ------------
 -3--------3-
```

Comment: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer."

Comment: If you need further help, please show your actual code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code currently shown is incomplete and also cannot be producing the exact output you claim it does (It has `"File"` in the `printf` which is not shown in the output).

Comment: here text is variable which stored file path and file name. It might be a problem in your case.

Comment: I don't have a problem. I'm just letting you know that code posted on Stack Overflow needs to be complete and minimal. People can't  compile your code to debug it if it is incomplete. And you need to post the **exact** code. The code you have posted does not match the output given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I found number of things that made the output of the files not as was intended. The main reason is number 1, the files' names problem and number 3.

1. Lets start with this code:

   ```
   snprintf(buf1, sizeof(buf1), "%s.txt", text);
   snprintf(buf2, sizeof(buf2), "%s.txt", text);
   ```

   Those two lines of code are somehow not written right. First of all, why would you want 
   to open the same file twice? You must change the "text" parameter to 2 different names. 
   Second, it is not appropriate to take the size of a buffer using sizeof(); You should 
   define a constant number.

   ```
   #define BUFF_SIZE 0x100
   ```
2. The next code my cause an error:

   ```
   if (fptr1 == NULL && fptr2==NULL)
   {
      printf("Cannot open files \n");
      exit(0);
   }
   ```

   Change the '&&' to '||', as you want to check that both of the files are open to be read off.
3. The next two lines are the main reason why the code isn't working:

   ```
   status1 = fgets(ch1, sizeof(ch1), fptr1);
   status2 = fgets(ch2, sizeof(ch2), fptr1);
   printf("File 1: %s", ch1);
   printf("File 2: %s", ch2);
   ```

   First of all, change the parameter given to 'fgets' function of the status2 variable to 'fptr2'. Second, you should add to the code the 3 next lines:

   ```
   size_t len1 = strcspn(ch1, "\n"), len2 = strcspn(ch2, "\n");
   ch1[(len1 < BUFF_FILE_SIZE) ? (len1) : (BUFF_FILE_SIZE - 1)] = 0;
   ch2[(len2 < BUFF_FILE_SIZE) ? (len2) : (BUFF_FILE_SIZE - 1)] = 0;
   ```

   Those 3 lines are searching for the "\n" charcter which is "new line" character and deletes if it is found and if not changes the last character in the buffer to null so the printf would know to when to stop the read off the buffer.
   Third, the printfs should look like:

   ```
   printf("%s ", ch1);
   printf("%s\n", ch2);
   ```

As you can see, I added a space in the first printf to seperate the two outputs of the two files and in the second file I added enter.

Now for the whole code:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 0x100
#define BUFF_FILE_SIZE 255
void printFiles(const char* text1, const char* text2)
{
    char* status1, * status2;
    char ch1[BUFF_FILE_SIZE], ch2[BUFF_FILE_SIZE];
    FILE* fptr1;
    FILE* fptr2;
    char buf1[BUFF_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char buf2[BUFF_SIZE] = { 0 };
    snprintf(buf1, BUFF_SIZE, "%s.txt", text1);
    snprintf(buf2, BUFF_SIZE, "%s.txt", text2);
    fptr1 = fopen(buf1, "r");
    fptr2 = fopen(buf2, "r");

    //  fptr = fopen(folder[5]+*c[i].val+text[3], "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL || fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open files \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Read contents from file 

    do {
        status1 = fgets(ch1, BUFF_FILE_SIZE, fptr1);
        status2 = fgets(ch2, BUFF_FILE_SIZE, fptr2);
        size_t len1 = strcspn(ch1, "\n"), len2 = strcspn(ch2, "\n");
        ch1[(len1 < BUFF_FILE_SIZE) ? (len1) : (BUFF_FILE_SIZE - 1)] = 0;
        ch2[(len2 < BUFF_FILE_SIZE) ? (len2) : (BUFF_FILE_SIZE - 1)] = 0;
        printf("%s ", ch1);
        printf("%s\n", ch2);
    } while (status1 || status2);

    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_N85mlJyQFR39SWcPXyUolnfa32GiZ1K/view?usp=sharing

you can download code and files from this link. Thank you.
 @kaylum

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_N85mlJyQFR39SWcPXyUolnfa32GiZ1K/view?usp=sharing
@Sean Tashlik  you can download code and files from this link. Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much @Sean Tashlik You've helped me a lot and your code answer solved y biggest problem. Best Regards.

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: I know this is super awkward, bu @Sean Tashlik t would you like to give me your email address or Whatsapp or any other way to contact if you don't mind. I would be honored. Thanks again